# Google App Engine with Spring Cloud GCP: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-data-jpa, google-cloud-sql

I've been working on trying to deploy to app engine for several days now. Little problems persist. At this point I can't tell if I'm actually able to connect to the DB from app engine or not. What I can tell you is that I have tested the login credentials from the command line and they all work.

## pom.xml

Flyway disabled during troubleshooting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>nathanlively</groupId>
    <artifactId>subaligner-css</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>subaligner</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <!-- Maven plugins -->
        <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.12.1</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion>v19.8.1</frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.npmVersion>9.5.1</frontend-maven-plugin.npmVersion>
        <spring-cloud-gcp.version>4.1.4</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency><!-- Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.15.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- gcloud stuff -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.html</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.css</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.svg</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <projectId>subaligner-382913</projectId>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install-frontend-tooling</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <nodeVersion>${frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion}</nodeVersion>
                                <npmVersion>${frontend-maven-plugin.npmVersion}</npmVersion>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>run-npm-install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>run-npm-build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>run build</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>run-npm-build</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run build-prod</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

## application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=deploy
#spring.cloud.gcp.sql.enabled=false

# ===============================
# = JPA / Hibernate
# ===============================
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=20MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=21MB

# ===============================
# = API
# ===============================
soundVelocityUrl=https://nathanlively.pythonanywhere.com/speedOfSound/?

# ===============================
# = Thymeleaf Config
# ===============================
spring.thymeleaf.template-resolver-order=0
spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages

# ===============================
# = MVC Config
# ===============================
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true

# ===============================
# = Redis Config
# ===============================
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=60000
spring.cache.redis.cache-null-values=true
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.redis.host=127.0.0.1
```

## application-deploy.properties

```
# ===============================
# = Deployed Database Config
# ===============================
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=subaligner_java
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=subaligner-382913:us-central1:subaligner-java
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.cloud.gcp.logging.enabled=true
spring.datasource.username=${sm://DB_USER/latest}
spring.datasource.password=${sm://DB_PASSWORD/latest}

# ===============================
# = Flyway Database Config
# ===============================
#spring.flyway.enabled=true
#spring.flyway.user=${sm://DB_USERFLYWAY/latest}
#spring.flyway.password=${sm://DB_PASSWORDFLY/latest}
```

## The Result

```
2023-04-12 16:43:33 default[1]  2023-04-12T16:43:33.322Z  INFO 12 --- [           main] n.subalignercss.SubalignerApplication    : Starting SubalignerApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.6 with PID 12 (/workspace/subaligner-css-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by www-data in /workspace)
2023-04-12 16:43:33 default[1]  2023-04-12T16:43:33.327Z  INFO 12 --- [           main] n.subalignercss.SubalignerApplication    : The following 1 profile is active: "deploy"
2023-04-12 16:43:35 default[1]  2023-04-12T16:43:35.686Z  INFO 12 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-04-12 16:43:35 default[1]  2023-04-12T16:43:35.689Z  INFO 12 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-04-12 16:43:37 default[1]  2023-04-12T16:43:37.529Z  INFO 12 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-04-12 16:43:37 default[1]  2023-04-12T16:43:37.547Z  INFO 12 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-04-12 16:43:37 default[1]  2023-04-12T16:43:37.547Z  INFO 12 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.7]
2023-04-12 16:43:37 default[1]  2023-04-12T16:43:37.727Z  INFO 12 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-04-12 16:43:37 default[1]  2023-04-12T16:43:37.730Z  INFO 12 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3795 ms
2023-04-12 16:43:38 default[1]  2023-04-12T16:43:38.564Z  INFO 12 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-04-12 16:43:38 default[1]  2023-04-12T16:43:38.701Z  INFO 12 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-04-12 16:43:39 default[1]  2023-04-12T16:43:39.311Z  INFO 12 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-04-12 16:43:42 default[1]  2023-04-12T16:43:42.544Z  WARN 12 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
2023-04-12 16:43:42 default[1]  Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-04-12 16:43:42 default[1]  2023-04-12T16:43:42.594Z ERROR 12 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2023-04-12 16:43:42 default[1]  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]      at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar!/:3.0.5]    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar!/:3.0.5]  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar!/:3.0.5]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar!/:3.0.5]      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar!/:3.0.5]     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar!/:3.0.5]     at nathanlively.subalignercss.SubalignerApplication.main(SubalignerApplication.java:13) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]      at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[subaligner-css-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[subaligner-css-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[subaligner-css-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[subaligner-css-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]  Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]      at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]      at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]      at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]      ... 24 common frames omitted  Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]   ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Why do you bring in old spring cloud gcp dependencies? They're not compatible with the latest boot and cloud

Comment: Hey @spencergibb , thanks for the question. I don't know the answer. I'm just following any and all documentation and tutorials I can find. Maybe you'd like to make some suggestions?

Comment: I just noticed it was odd. I can't comment on the rest of the issue. Remove spring cloud gcp 1.x

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb . Are you referring to the dependencyManagement? If so, that's exactly what gets installed when you run Spring Initializer and include GCP support. Is not no longer recommended?

Comment: It does not give you 1.2.3.RELEASE that is in your pom

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb , I guess I'm not completely understanding the suggestion you're making here.

Comment: Remove org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:1.2.3.RELEASE

Comment: thanks @spencergibb , I tried that. It generated an error with the starter-secretmanager dependency, but I fixed that by changing the group id to com.google.cloud. Now I'm getting a login error so I guess the secretmanager is not working for some reason. I could hard code the password, but that won't be a long term solution.

Answer (score 2):

For now  this problem has been solved by following @spencergibb 's suggestion above and hard coding the datasource username and password. I'm not happy with it, but I figured it was better to put something here.